# How do animals end up in remote areas?

Tags: zoology, ecology, species-distribution, migration

I was thinking specifically about random marshy water holes on farmers fields. It seems that you can visit just about any one of these and you will find frogs if you look hard enough.

They usually don't seem to be connected to each other. If it were any other land animal I would figure they walk from one spot to another, but in the case of frogs, I don't imagine their range is very vast. But often these marshy spots can be separated by fairly large distances to a frog.

So this brings me to my question: **how do each of these spots end up with frogs in them?**  I don't imagine a frog is going to go hopping over a hill to get to a marsh on the other side, is it?

Comment: The same with fish - how on Earth do they find their way to isolated lakes?! ! I love this question. +1

Comment: I have read that hurricanes can carry animals up into them and displace them. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rain_of_animals#Frogs_and_toads

Comment: First, i would look at statistics:
just because (hypothesis) you visit 1000 watering holes /marshes a year and they have frogs in them it doesn't mean that its a common occurrence; Second, i think froglings (yeah, i know :D ) hatch whenever there is rain, grow, mate and deposit new eggs that survive droughts. Now, these can be relocated by earth movements and birds and wind (i don't think frog rains could help with this level of dispersal).
Basically, they don't end up in remote areas; They were already there in some form.

Comment: I think you should narrow down the question (question title) to frogs (if you are mostly interested in those), or a group of organisms with similar biologies. "*Animals*" is too unspecific, and answers will differ widely between organism groups (e.g. birds, rats, frogs, dragonflies, fish etc), so the question is "Too broad".

Comment: You should clarify how great is the distance between two nearest habitats for a certain organism. Frogs can move about in some range. Sometimes their eggs or tadpoles can get washed away with runoff water to land up in distant places.

Comment: You would understand it much better when you consider the fact that your question encompasses a geographical aspect more than a biological one, the biological aspect being the creation of a new habitat. Migration/dispersal of offsprings from their parents depends much more geographical aspects such as lay of the land or climate. These links may be of some interest. http://goo.gl/JL1vp3 , http://goo.gl/agcr0d , http://goo.gl/6vb6yp

Comment: @Koustav, yes it seems to make more sense being dependant on droughts and floods rather than by glaciation as suggested by MattDMo. Your comment would be better as an answer.

Comment: If you are a creation believing person, then the universal flood clearly gives the answer you are seeking about fishes @AliceD

Comment: @OneFace - I'm not and if I were, it still does not explain why fishes inhabit *new* puddles formed *after* the universal flood :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This question pertains to organism dispersal, which is a very active field of study with relation to it's impact on conservation efforts. Much of what I will say below has been covered in this [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Biological_dispersal).

**Definition: From the Wiki**

> Technically, dispersal is defined as any movement that has the
>   potential to lead to gene flow.

It can be broadly classified into two categories:

1. Density dependent dispersal
2. Density independent dispersal

The question of frogs and fishes both refer to Density independent dispersal, while an example of density independent dispersal can be the [competition for habitat space between big cats and humans](http://goo.gl/UQNF76) (this is a WWF pdf)

From the wiki:

> **Density-independent dispersal**
>
> Organisms have evolved adaptations for dispersal that take advantage
>   of various forms of kinetic energy occurring naturally in the
>   environment. This is referred to as density independent or passive
>   dispersal and operates on many groups of organisms (some
>   invertebrates, fish, insects and sessile organisms such as plants)
>   that depend on animal vectors, wind, gravity or current for dispersal.
>
> **Density-dependent dispersal**
>
> Density dependent or active dispersal for many animals largely depends
>   on factors such as local population size, resource competition,
>   habitat quality, and habitat size.

Currently, some studies suggest the same.

[This study](http://goo.gl/JL1vp3) in particular studied the movement and habitat occupancy patterns within ephemeral and permanent water bodies in response to flooding. They found that during flooding these frogs moved out to flooded ephemeral water bodies and later on moved back again to the permanent ones.

Other suggested readings for those highly interested in the subject may include [this](http://goo.gl/agcr0d) (a phd thesis) and [this](http://goo.gl/6vb6yp) (a project report)

Answer (score 5):

> I don't imagine a frog is going to go hopping over a hill to get to a marsh on the other side, is it?

Why not? In wet weather, the conditions would be just fine for an enterprising amphibian to go exploring, perhaps driven by predators or lack of available resources, not to mention Ro Siv's [comment](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/36561/how-do-animals-end-up-in-remote-areas#comment60872_36561) about [wind-borne dispersal of animals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rain_of_animals). Birds of prey may also pick up small animals, fly away with them, then drop them for whatever reason.

You are also neglecting the fact that these organisms have existed for millions of years, and the landscape has changed tremendously in that time, with [glacial periods](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glacial_period) interspersed with [interglacials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interglacial) every 20-50,000 years or so. As glaciers melt, large lakes form, and as those dried the organisms were dispersed across the land into smaller bodies of water. Streams and rivers form, transporting aquatic life forms, and may dry out and form isolated ponds, or they may be blocked for any number of reasons (mudslides, earthquakes, volcanic eruptions, beaver dams, fallen trees, etc.). As erosion and landscape remodeling occur, all traces of the original body of water may be erased, except for the wide distribution of similar organisms.

Comment: Yes, but marshes have come and gone on an almost yearly basis (or over several years, maybe a decade or so). We're not talking eons here.

Comment: @Octopus marshy areas tend to remain marshy areas over the short term (decades to centuries) unless acted upon by an outside force, such as the rerouting of a water supply or human activity. I'm not sure what you mean by coming and going on an almost yearly basis - could you give some examples? Also, as I mentioned in my answer, during prolonged wet weather (maybe over a week or more), frogs and other amphibians could travel relatively long distances with ease. I'm not terribly close to wetlands, yet I often find frogs in my yard during/after a long rain that are no longer there when it's dry.